# table in Angular with Pagination/Sort/Filter

Tags: angular, html-table

I am new to angular and have learnt only the basics.

1. I want to create a Table which will fetch data to load from server. Which Approach should i follow?
2. I want to fetch data from server based on the no of records in the page. If i click 2nd page then it should hit server to get next 10 records. How can it be done?
3. I want give an input in GUI where the user can search from all the records. How to implement that?

Comment: Do not use the jQuery DataTables library which has been hacked into Angular. Instead, use Material Admin (mat) Tables. It would be much easier to add widgets to the mat table verses dealing with bugs generated by jQuery DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Use data-table. It has both server side processing and client side. Check the link below

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

To get started, please follow the link
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

Comment: do i need to install any specific package?

Comment: i am getting error angular-datatables@4.4.0 requires a peer of core-js@~2.4.1 but none was installed. Not able to find solution.

Comment: How are you doing that? Please do a fresh install. It should work